# Using a symlink as base directory of a Tomcat webapp

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, symlink

I'm running Tomcat 6 on Ubuntu.
I have webapps stored outside the webapps folder of tomcat6, I used to symlink them and it worked like a charm.

For instance, in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/, I have a symlink 'webapp1' pointing to ~/webapp1, which has the proper content for a webapp.
It works fine, webapp1 is up and running in the blink of an eye.

Now if I create another link to /media/someotherdisk/webapp2, it doesn't work at all.
webapp2 has the required content to be detected, it has the same access rights as webapp1, as well for the content itself. I checked all I could think of and I don't understand the difference for Tomcat.

So why is it acting this way? And how can I make it to work the same as for 'webapp1'?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Tomcat after you added the 2nd symlink?

Comment: Is allowLinking set to true, can the user the Tomcat process is running as read the target of the symlink, are there any error in the logs...

Comment: @ChrisWhite I'm pretty sure I did, but I will try again to make sure

Comment: @MarkThomas I didnt see anything in the logs, but I realize I left them on the default level. I'll try to change that too. I've come to think it is indeed a matter of access rights, hopefuly I can test further later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a simple permission problem.

`/media/someotherdisk/webapp2/` was alright (+rx for anyone) but `/media/someotherdisk/` had no permission set except for the its owner.

I dont know why it was this way for this partition in particular and not for the other mounted partitions, but changing permissions solved my problem.